# VB.NET - 3rd part Web Service method returns Nothing

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, wsdl

I'm developing a VB.NET app using Visual Studio 2010.

I added the reference to this WS: http://cofam.org.ar:81/webService/Validador/ValidadorCofam.asmx?WSDL

and made this code:

```
Try
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument
    doc.Load("pathtoxmlfile")
    Dim vr2 As New WSCofamTesting.ValidadorCofamSoapClient
    Dim result As XmlNode
    result = vr2.Valida("asd", "asd", doc.DocumentElement)

Catch ex As Exception
    mvarMsgError = ex.ToString
    Add2Log(MyName & "-GestionarWSCOFAM.Error:" & mvarMsgError)
End Try
```

As the user and password (asd) doesn't exist, at least I should get a "wrong user/password", but the method "Valida" returns Nothing. The xml file that I send is well writed, the developer of the WS sent me it. Here is a copy:

```
<Validador xmlns="http://www.cofam.org.ar/WebService/Validador">
  <Transaccion>
    <Operacion>AutorizarReceta</Operacion>
    <Version>01.00</Version>
    <Fecha>13/01/2016</Fecha>
    <Hora>13:01:00</Hora>
  </Transaccion>
  <Sistema>
    <SistemaID>BT</SistemaID>
    <SistemaHK />
    <SistemaVER>3.0.0.7</SistemaVER>
    <SistemaMsgID>000005</SistemaMsgID>
    <Puesto>PC00</Puesto>
  </Sistema>
  <Comercio>
    <CodCOFAM>9999</CodCOFAM>
    <ComercioID>990</ComercioID>
  </Comercio>
  <Mensaje>
    <AutorizarReceta>
      <ObraSocial>239</ObraSocial>
      <Plan>2</Plan>
      <Afiliado>1027224300</Afiliado>
      <Convenio />
      <Receta>0</Receta>
      <FechaMedico>10/01/2016</FechaMedico>
      <FechaDispensa>13/01/2016</FechaDispensa>
      <Medico>MP00000321</Medico>
      <Diagnostico />
      <TipoTratamiento>NO</TipoTratamiento>
      <Items>
        <Item>     
          <Registro>34959</Registro>
          <Descripcion />
          <Cantidad>1</Cantidad>
          <Importe>64,05</Importe>
          <PorcentajeOS>50,00</PorcentajeOS>
          <ImportOS>0</ImportOS>
        </Item>
      </Items>
    </AutorizarReceta>
  </Mensaje>
</Validador>
```

I tried using the Web Reference, Service Reference, result variable with type XmlNode, XmlDocument, XmlElement; also calling the method from the "instant window" with ?vs2.valida("asd", "asd", doc.Element). Also the developer of the WS couldn't find anything wrong in my code and with his app in C++ the method works perfect. He also sent me the code of that app and it's the same of mine.

If any one have any idea of what can be the cause or need more information about the code to have a clear vision of the problem, feel free to reply.

Thanks a lot.